# Linearized Einstein equation on a general background metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, linearized-theory

All of my texts only give the Linearized Einstein equation on the Minkowski background so I thought I'd try and figure it out by hand today.

Using the standard perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ and denoting the trace reversed perturbation: $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}=h_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}h$, I chose the (useful) Lorentz gauge condition    $\bar{h}_{\quad,\nu}^{\mu\nu}=0
 $
and arrived at:
$$\frac{-c^{4}}{16\pi G_{N}}(\square\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}+R_{\:\mu\:\nu}^{\alpha\:\beta}\bar{h}_{\alpha\beta})-\delta T_{\mu\nu}=0$$
Where the $\delta T_{\mu\nu}$ is the Stress energy tensor of the perturbing body.

Now, I did this by hand so I wouldn't be surprised to have made errors. I've only been able to find this to compare it with:
[Linearized Einstein Equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41629/) 
which makes me think I'm off by a factor of 2. Can anyone point me towards a book where they actually show the general case?

Comment: Does Wald's GR book, section 7.5 to equation 7.5.23, cover what you need?

Comment: Yes, the derivation to 7.5.23  is what I needed to compare. They were doing a vacuum solution, but I don't see why that would affect my results, other than perhaps a constant factor over everything, thanks!